# Ebean Where with OR (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean

I am trying to write an expression that should give me all "clips" where the `currentUserId` is the `creator`, or the `clip` is being `sharedWith` the given `currentUserId`.

`creator` is a one-to-many (a creator can have many clips), and `sharedWith` is a many-to-many (many `clip`s can be shared with many users):

```
Clip.find.where().or(
      eq("creator.id", currentUserId),
      eq("sharedWith.id", currentUserId)
);
```

The above returns only clips where the clip is being shared with the `currentUserId`, so it omitted the OR.

I tried using Junctions:

```
Clip.find.where().disjunction()
                    .add(eq("creator.id", currentUserId))
                    .add(eq("sharedWith.id", currentUserId)).endJunction();
```

And it returns the same result.

I'm using Play Framework 2 if it is of any matter.

I'd prefer to avoid using RawSql, as these are not the only expressions being added (however I did remove the others to see if it worked, so it is of no relevance).

EDIT:

I wrote the query that should return the correct results:

```
select * from clip
join user u on (clip.creator_id = u.id)
left outer join user_clip uc on (clip.id = uc.clip_id)
where (u.id = 1) or (uc.user_id = 1)
```

How do I get Ebean to generate this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it - I used `raw` expressions:

```
Clip.find.where().raw("(sharedWith.id = ?) or (creator.id = ?)", new Object[]{currentUserId, currentUserId});
```

It generated the following SQL:

```
select distinct t0.clip_type c0, t0.id c1, t0.clip_type c2, t0.created_at c3, t0.creator_id c4, t0.text c5, t0.image_src c6 
from clip t0 
left outer join user_clip t1z_ on t1z_.clip_id = t0.id  
left outer join user t1 on t1.id = t1z_.user_id  
where (t1.id = 1) or (t0.creator_id = 1)
```